# Passing values that aren't related to inputs using MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have page where users can select from one or more images.  When they are done I would like them to navigate to the next page and what is displayed would be based on the selection from the previous page.

"Selecting" just means that they click the image and it has a CSS class added to it.  When they click the link to navigate to the next page I'd like to collect the images that have been selected and pass that information along using either `TempData` or `Session`.

In most of the examples I have seen either inputs or the query string is used to pass information from the View to the Controller.  How can I pass which elements have a particular class to my controller when a link is clicked?

Comment: If your wanting to post rather than constructing a (possibly) ugly query string, you could create hidden inputs with the image ID, then  enable or disable the associated input based on selection. Your post method would then accept an array of the ID's (disabled controls don't post back).

Comment: @StephenMuecke - very interesting.  So is the only way to get information from the view to the controller to have an `input` or include it in the query string?

Comment: In addition to form fields (input, select, textarea) and query string parameters, you can also use values in the JSON Request for ajax calls. I suspect posting back form fields, persisting them (e.g. session) and then redirecting would be best in your case but hard to be sure without knowing what you rendering in the view, and how you uniquely identify images

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a link click, I'd probably just append the selected images to the query string. I'm assuming you don't mind exposing this query string to end users.

I'm sure that's probably not the answer you were looking for. But as you stated I think you're only to legitimate options are passing the values through the query string or using hidden inputs and posting the page to your action by intercepting the link click event.

Comment: Hmm, well if I'm not opposed to posting back what would be the best way to accomplish this?  Basically all I want to do is post the data back to a different action in the same controller.  Sorry if this is obvious - I'm used to using webforms.

Answer (score 0):

You said you do not want to post back to servers. You cannot access **TempData** or **Session** without posting back to server, so they are out of scope.

You only have client side option, so you want to collect a user's selected items in array.

Once the user clicks to **Next Page**, you create a query string like this `?ids=1-2-3-4` and retrieve those value at next page.

***Other thoughts:*** Long URL likes this is a bit ugly, and URL has maximum length limit depending on browser. If I'm you, I'll post back to server to collect the selected values. Then use TempData (or some persistent storage).

Comment: I don't think I said that, but if I did - I was incorrect.  I happen to be using an anchor tag for navigation, but I'm not opposed to doing a post back.